# Hide branch for scm user group

Tags: svn, version-control, scmmanager

I am looking for a solution with our svn repo.

We have the issue, that we collaborate with a second party on a certain svn project.
So, now we don't want, that they have access to all the branches.

Imagine the structure:

- trunk
- branches

  - br1
  - br2

How do i configure this, that the second party only sees e.g. br2? I know this is working with other svn servers. There is the plugin that restricts access to a certain path, but for that you need to have at least read access set to permissions for the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible (at least not without a lot of fuss) due to the common base for svn, git and hg in SCM-Manager.

What you can try though are svn externals.